# Create custom macro

Tags: eclipse, macros, eclipselink

I´d like to create my own macro in eclipse, which should be able to load my python code to a external control. The optimal solution would be to create a little key, which could be added in the toolbar, which should do the assignment.
How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out practicalMacro here:
[practicalMacro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro)

Also there is AutoHotKey but I have not used that one.